# Custom OG image with object doesnt appear with full width and height

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

i have been tried with custom open graph objects to make photo look bigger on facebook wall when it is shared just like how Flickr images shows in news feed when shared. I used the same OG code and also made custom object type but still no success in appearing it same as how Flickr links appear. I also tried to search on FB documentation for the same. Didnt find any information regarding this. I know about Explicit image shared.

**Below is the image shared from Flickr Link:**
[image]

**Below is the image shared from my site:**
[image]

OG Code:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# namespace: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/namespace#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123-APP-ID-456" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="namespace:photos" data-dynamic="true" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="URL" data-dynamic="true" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Photos" data-dynamic="true" /> 
<meta name="og:site_name" content="GoldenGoa"  data-dynamic="true" />
<meta name="og:image:width" content="640"  data-dynamic="true">
<meta name="og:image:height" content="427"  data-dynamic="true">
<meta property="og:image"  content="http://link-to-single-photo.jpg" data-dynamic="true" /> 
 </head>
```

Please help me in solving this issue. Will be thankfull of you. Good Day

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your og:url is same as your real link - Facebook will follow og:url. You can use OpenGraph Debugger [0] to view scraped data.

[0] - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Its the same URL to link and imae still same issue. it is not visible as wide and big image from url